# Finding the shape created by two other intersecting shapes

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, shapes

I have two overlapping shapes in my C# app, defined by `Point` arrays. I need to find the points that define the shape where these two overlap. In this image, I know the red and green points, but I need the yellow points.

[image]

Here is some dummy code that might help:

```
Point[] GetIntersection(Point[] red, Point[] green)
{
    Point[] yellow = ?!?;

    return yellow;
}
```

There are certainly ways you could do this assuming nice easy rectangles. In practice, I need to be able to handle polygons and maybe even circles (although I can live without circles).

Any ideas? I'm hoping there is a nifty GDI+ function that will just spit this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the [`Region::Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534804(v=VS.85).aspx) method does what you want.

Comment: @Miky - I tried it with a polygon and it worked fine (you have to create a `GraphicsPath` from the polygon point array).